# View current user sessions on Azure virtual machines

Tags: azure

Before we start using Azure's virtual machines we're interested if there's a similar mechanism to qwinsta command that can be used to retrieve current user sessions from virtual machines and also like qwinsta returns us information about which ones are free. I've had a Google but haven't found anything, can someone please point me in to the right direction with this? What is the right approach to achieve this?
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a result from an Azure VM running Windows Server 2012:

```
PS D:\Users\***> query session
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
 services                                    0  Disc
 console                                     1  Conn
>rdp-tcp#1         ***                       2  Active
 rdp-tcp                                 65536  Listen
```

(Usrename was removed for security reasons)

You can also [enable remote PowerShell on the Azure VM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sriharsha/archive/2013/10/26/remote-powershell-in-azure-iaas-virtual-machines.aspx) and remotely execute PowerShell script.